# BoxWhiskerChart without the data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, charts

I have the following for a dataset, but I do not have the underlying data:

- Mean
- Median
- Q1
- Q3
- range OR max(data) & min(data)

Is it possible for me to draw the BoxWhiskerChart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the option `Method` with suboption `"BoxRange"`:

```
ClearAll[boxRange]
boxRange = #[[{5, 3, 2, 4, 6}]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
summary = {mean, median, q1, q2, min, max} = {5, 6, 3, 7, 1, 9};
summaries = {summary , 2 + summary , 1 + summary};
BoxWhiskerChart[summaries, 
 ChartStyle -> 97, 
 Method -> {"BoxRange" -> boxRange}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassBoxWhisker"]
```

[image]

If you need to add the mean marker, you can pre-process input data to create new lists with the required means:

```
ClearAll[preProcess]
preProcess = Module[{d = Append[#, t]}, d /. Solve[Mean[d] == d[[1]], t][[1]]] &;

BoxWhiskerChart[preProcess /@ summaries, {{"MeanMarker", 1, Red}}, 
 ChartStyle -> 97,
 Method -> {"BoxRange" -> boxRange},  
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassBoxWhisker"]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative way to add mean markers is to use a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[f_: "BoxWhisker"] := {ChartElementData[f][##], PointSize[Large], 
    If[#3 === {}, {}, Point@Thread[{Mean[#[[1]]], #3[[1]]}]], White, 
    Thick, Dashed, Line[Thread[{#[[1]], #2[[1]]}]]} &;

BoxWhiskerChart[summaries, 
 ChartStyle -> 98, 
 Method -> {"BoxRange" -> boxRange}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ceF["GlassBoxWhisker"]]
```

[image]

The function `ceF` can also be used to show outliers by using them as metadata in the first argument of `BoxWhiskerChart`:

```
outliers = {{12, 13, 14}, {1, 13, 15}, {12, 13}};
BoxWhiskerChart[Thread[summaries -> outliers], 
 ChartStyle -> 98, 
 Method -> {"BoxRange" -> boxRange}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ceF["GlassBoxWhisker"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, now the next part is, if I know that there are three outliers (at the top end of the box and whisker diagram) is it possible to include three points too?

Comment: I actually also have the min and the max, not just the range, so that removes the symmetry issue.

Comment: @wilsnunn, maybe yo can use `Epilog` to add outliers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty way to do it..

```
val = {{1, 4, 9/2, 5, 9}, {4, 5, 11/2, 6, 8}};(*min,Q1,Median,Q3,max,*)

col = ColorData[97, #] & /@ Range@Length@val;
fence = 0.05;
boxWidth = 0.1;

Show[Table[Graphics[{Black,

    (*wisker*)Line[{{i, val[[i, 1]]}, {i, val[[i, 5]]}}],
    (*lower fence*)
    Line[{{i - fence, val[[i, 1]]}, {i + fence, val[[i, 1]]}}],

    (*upper fence*)
    Line[{{i - fence, val[[i, 5]]}, {i + fence, val[[i, 5]]}}],

    (*box*)col[[i]], 
    Rectangle[{i - boxWidth, val[[i, 2]]}, {i + boxWidth, 
      val[[i, 4]]}],

    (*median*)Red, 
    Line[{{i - boxWidth, val[[i, 3]]}, {i + boxWidth, val[[i, 3]]}}]

    }, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/1.2], {i, Length@val}]]
```

[image]